# Https for localhost with plaid api

Tags: api, https, server, localhost, plaid

I'm playing around with the plaid api. I have the sandbox working and wanted to start using real data. That would require https. I need to get local host "secure".

I've tried following a few tutorials online with no luck, mkcert...

Any help with that or another method to use plaids api with development data would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions in this Stack Overflow answer worked for me: [Starting a react app in HTTPS instead of HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54445498/starting-a-react-app-in-https-instead-of-http)

Also, one thing you can try -- definitely not recommended as a long term solution, but if you really just want to mess around with a couple of accounts in Development, it's ok -- you could skip the OAuth setup and do it later, since IIRC it's only OAuth that requires https.  But make sure to implement OAuth before going to Production!